# What doctype declaration is required for CSS focus selector to work in IE8 and IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, doctype

I'm trying to use the CSS :focus selector which works fine in Mozilla Firefox but appears to have no effect in IE8 or IE9.

W3schools notes that DOCTYPE must be declared for focus to work in IE8 but it does not specify what the doctype should be.

My CSS:

```
#form1 input:focus
{
    background: #e1ebfe;
    border: 1px solid #00AADD;
}
```

I have tried the following DOCTYPEs but neither seem to work for 'focus'.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Both trigger standards mode so `:focus` should work. Don't you have a comment before the doctype? Please send a link to live demo.

Comment: live demo here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/La8xf/)

Comment: @duri It seems that this works... The problem must be in my live code. I have declared the doctype on the first line of my markup. I'm still not sure what the issue is.

Comment: This works because jsfiddle adds doctype by itself. Try opening document where `:focus` doesn't work, paste `javascript:alert(document.compatMode)` into address bar (or better type it because IE9 removes `javascript:` when pasting into address bar) and press enter. If the result is `BackCompat`, the doctype was not declared properly. If the result is `CSS1Compat`, then doctype is OK and there's something other that causes the issue.

Comment: @duri I've tested on my own server with and without doctype. Turns out the issue was with IE and it's Compatibility Mode in both IE8 and IE9. Thanks again for all your feedback! Sorry for my noobishness!

Comment: Please note that by default, Compatibilty View is Enabled for Intranet sites in IE8.

Comment: Doctypes are never an option for new web sites and are required. Without a doctype, you are in quirks mode where you never want to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New web pages should always use a strict doctype. Transitional is for pages that are transitioning from old, deprecated markup which new web pages should not be using. Use either the strict one you show or the new one: `<!DOCTYPE html>` which will put IE8 into standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the list of available doctypes, try them :)
[w3schools DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Comment: Tried these already. The issue must be within my markup, sorry! Thanks anyway

Comment: Never experiment with doctypes. Doctypes are a technical decision made before anything else is put in the markup. See my answer.

Comment: Or, here is the _OFFICIAL_ list: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: @Rob Point taken :) A good Doctype decision should avoid the need for any recoding. I'm glad doctype wasn't the issue here!